How to plot the history of download and upload per hour for a given service or process on Windows 10?
I saw on https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/does-dosvc-download-anything-other-than-windows/25b1812f-cbc2-4797-92b4-ac87f1b2aea0 the history of download and upload per hour  for the DoSvc service on Windows 10:

How to plot the history of download and upload per hour  for a  given service or process on Windows 10?

One way is to use a third-party tool, such as Glasswire
